# Asp.Net MVC Site with more Images - Need CDN recommendation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cdn, azure-cdn

I currently have a Travel site built using Asp.Net MVC. The site have many articles and albums with lot of images asssociated with it. Currently, we are uploading the images locally to a folder and linking it in the article content and similarly for the albums too. Since the number of images are growing day by day, there are more loads on the webserver for every request which downloads lots of images. 
I have seen other sites where they do similar thing by referring the images alone from a subdomain and some using CDN.

I am currently having shared hosting site plan and i need to reduce the stress to webserver by rendering the image from elsewhere.
Is there any CDN recommendation that is not so costly but can integrate well with my ASP.Net MVC site? I want to only upload the image to a CDN and link the image from CDN instead of local folder from the article posting page.

If CDN is not the option, can anyone suggest something else to serve my purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: You only need a CDN if you're moving hundreds of gigabytes of images a day: millions of requests. As you're on a shared hosting plan it's more likely the server is overwhelmed, especially if you're naively storing data in the filesystem without memory caching (probably not even in a SAN either, if your webhost is low-rent).

Comment: I suggest upgrading to a managed hosting provider, a dedicated server, or a high-end VM, the cost of doing this will probably be less than the cost of moving to a CDN anyway, and you get the benefit of higher all-round perf (and probably better customer service).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You need to move content to CDN. Because CDN provides very huge speed over network and it will reduce traffic to your web server.

There are very high range of CDN's available in market. I would suggest some of those for your purpose.

1. CDN77
2. Azure
3. MAXCDN
4. Akamai

From all above, CDN77 and Azure are less costly than others as per my experience.

and also you should try CDN77 14days free trial for testing purpose.

Thanks,
Hayat S.